# How to replace notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am working on push notification in  iPhone app but i don't know how to replace old notification with new notification. 
Currently i am using apns-collapse-id but its not working . I am using FCM for push notification.
Stack-overflow in search, But i'm not getting proper answer.

I'm using this API to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send to send iOS push notification

==> **Here is my json payload**

$headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . $FIREBASE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
                         'apns-collapse-id':'1'
        );

Comment: what do you mean replace old notification? Can you explain more with details what you want to achieve and after that what did you try?

Comment: I dont think you can replace a notification, apns-collapse-id is used to group them: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

Comment: I think Whatsapp does this, removes the notification once message is deleted from everyone. But i don't know how.

Comment: @m1sh0 suppose i have one noptification showing cricket score i wanna updated that score so i wanna replace old notification with new one .

Comment: @Digvijay, you are right, sorry

Comment: did you try to add collapse_key, without the header :?

Comment: @m1sh0 yes i tried all possible solution but none of worked.

Comment: @Scriptable check knuff app. it ssupport collapse id and replace notification.

Comment: Hi I was wondering if you have worked out how to do this yet